# Postgres truncates CASE statement column

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I'm writing some functions for mapping a Postgres database. The functions are used to create dynamic queries for a javascript API.

I've come across a particular query that truncates the output of a column and I cannot determine why.

The width of the column in the following query seems to be truncated to 63 characters:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN t.column_name ~ '_[uid]*$' AND t.has_fn THEN
      format(
        'format(''%s/%%s'', %s) AS %s',
        array_to_string(ARRAY['',t.fk_schema,t.fk_name],'/'),
        t.column_name,
        regexp_replace(t.column_name, '_[uid]*$', '_link')
      )
    ELSE t.column_name
  END AS column
FROM core.map_type() t; -- core.map_type() is a set returning function
```

This query is used to create a select list for another query, but the string produced by `format()` is truncated to 63 characters.

However, if I add `|| ''` to the `ELSE` branch of the `CASE` statement, the problem goes away:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN t.column_name ~ '_[uid]*$' AND t.has_fn THEN
      format(
        'format(''%s/%%s'', %s) AS %s',
        array_to_string(ARRAY['',t.fk_schema,t.fk_name],'/'),
        t.column_name,
        regexp_replace(t.column_name, '_[uid]*$', '_link')
      )
    ELSE t.column_name || '' -- add empty string here
  END AS column
FROM core.map_type() t; -- core.map_type() is a set returning function
```

Having a column truncated like this is a worrisome problem. The fix here is a total hack and does not feel like a real solution.

Why is this happening? How can it be fixed?

Comment: What is the datatype of ```t.column_name```?

Comment: `name` the postgres type for names of tables, columns, etc

Comment: ... which has a fixed size of 64 bytes

Comment: Actually a ```\dT name``` in psql yields: "63-byte type for storing system identifiers". I guess it is a combination of this fact and of type resolving in ```CASE```, that your first query resolves to ```name```, while your second does so to ```text```. I haven't worked it out completely, but this link might help: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-union-case.html

Comment: I cannot make a sense out of this information or it might be due to version changes.. What is your version? And what do you get from following query: ```select typname, typispreferred from pg_type where typcategory = 'S';``` (I am interested in the "preferredness" of types ```name``` and ```text```.)

Comment: `name` typispreferred is `false`, `text` typispreferred is `true`. Would the `ELSE` branch designate the base type of the `CASE` statement? If it does, then it makes sense.

Comment: No, as I understand it depends just on the types, not on where they occur. Since ```format()``` returns ```text``` and both ```text``` and ```name``` are in the same category (```S```), I expected rule 5 to resolve the type to ```text```. Perhaps someone else can explain this...

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the value of `t.column_name` in the `ELSE` branch of the `CASE` statement is of type `name`. `name` is a type used internally by Postgres for naming things. It has a fixed length of 64 bytes.

The column is truncated to suit the length of the `ELSE` branch.

Casting `t.column_name` to `text` will fix the problem:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN t.column_name ~ '_[uid]*$' AND t.has_fn THEN
      format(
        'format(''%s/%%s'', %s) AS %s',
        array_to_string(ARRAY['',t.fk_schema,t.fk_name],'/'),
        t.column_name,
        regexp_replace(t.column_name, '_[uid]*$', '_link')
      )
    ELSE t.column_name::text
  END AS column
FROM core.map_type() t;
```